# I want to show only the latest SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some issues with duplicate SQL tables. When I run the query, I am looking to show the MOST recent “Order ID.” When I run the program, it will show me every single order ID from the company. I only want to pull the latest order ID. Is there something wrong with my query? Is there something I can add or remove?

I want to see the latest order number, currently I see them all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    payee.id AS 'Carrier ID' 
    , payee.status AS 'Status' 
    , CASE 
        WHEN payee.status = 'I' THEN 0 
        WHEN payee.status = 'A' THEN 100 
        ELSE 0 
        END AS 'Active %' 
    , drs_payee.icc_number AS 'MC #' 
    , payee.name AS 'Name' 
    , CAST(drs_payee.liab_expire_date AS DATE) AS 'Liab Date' 
    , CAST(drs.payee.cargo_ins_renew_dt AS DATE) AS 'Cargo Date' 
    , CONCAT(contact.email,'; ' ,drs_payee.ins_expire_notify) AS 'Emails' 
    , orders.id AS 'Order ID' 
    --, CAST(stop.sched_arrive_early AS DATE) AS 'Delivery Date'

FROM payee
    LEFT JOIN drs_payee ON payee.id = drs_payee.id
    INNER JOIN contact ON payee.id = contact.parent_row_id
    LEFT JOIN movement ON payee.id = movement.override_payee_id
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.curr_movement_id = movement.id
    LEFT JOIN stop ON movement.dest_stop_id = stop.sched_arrive_early

WHERE contact.sequence = '1'
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Given your query has no `where` clause, its not going to filter out any rows. Also in SQL Server you shouldn't be quoting your column aliases with single quotes, you should be using square brackets (and then only if required).

Comment: You're missing half of the SQL Statement - its missing the FROM Table and it doesn't look like you've hung around to field comments? Without a WHERE clause its impossible to give you an answer and hence the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: I added the complete query I use to pull all the loads. Every time I run the query it shows all the loads, and I just want to see the latest load from each carrier. @JeremyThompson

Comment: Ok, just be sure to hang around for a few mins after asking a question, this site is active~! This is just a guess but are you sure all the LEFT JOINS are needed? You want one record returned right? Does it return one record if you use all INNER JOINS?

Comment: I sure will. Would you suggest removing all of the Left Joins and running the query again with only the Inner Joins? I was thinking about trying to add MAX to the query at first. @JeremyThompson

Comment: Please do and then check the query results, what JOIN strategy will give you one record with the condition `WHERE contact.sequence = '1'`

Comment: If you provide sample data and desired results as requested you will shortcut all the questions and get a fast answer.

Comment: Without some more detail on the table schema and a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this is basically unanswerable. I would *suggest* you can remove the outer join to `orders` and replace it with a *correlated subquery* to select the max ID per `curr_movement_id`

Comment: `WHERE contact.sequence = '1'` Is this column defined as varchar or some numeric datatype? I doubt it is varchar - if true why do you use a string constant and rely on implicit conversion?

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `ORDER BY [column_name] desc` along with query and `LIMIT` if required.

Comment: Limit is not SQL Server